# Python raw_input how to take in multiple values at once

Tags: python, string, input

I want to use the raw_input function to take in multiple values.

```
inp = raw_input("--->")

--> 10, Trees, 40, Desks
```

`inp` now equals `'10,Trees,40,Desks'`

Rather, I want `inp` to be something like

```
'10','Trees','40', 'Desks'
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

use split...

```
  print inp.split(",")
```

or even better maybe

```
>>> inp = raw_input("->")
->10 trees,40 desks
>>> p1 = inp.split(",")
>>> p2 = dict([s.split() for s in p1])
>>> p2
{'10': 'trees', '40': 'desks'}
>>> p2 = dict([reversed(s.split()) for s in p1])
>>> p2
{'trees': '10', 'desks': '40'}
```

to make the values ints you can do

```
>>> for key in p2:
...     p2[key] = int(p2[key])
...
>>> p2
{'trees': 10, 'desks': 40}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `dict()`, you can also try: `dict((p1[x],p1[x-1]) for x in xrange(1,len(p1),2))`, no need of `reveresed()` in this case.
`

Comment: yeah ... I dunno this seemed like the more pythonic way(imho) ... but good suggestion(and probably faster)

Comment: yes it should be faster, as in this there's no requirement of `split()`.

Comment: Is there any way to make it check to see if the item entered is an integer, so that it doesn't save it as a string in the list? so that inp = [10,'trees',40,'desks']

Comment: @user1530318 type checking is not encouraged in python.

Comment: you assume that it is and then if it raises an exception you handle it

Comment: @user1530318 I added an example of that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = raw_input("--->").split(',')
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it check to see if the item entered is an integer, so that it doesn't save it as a string in the list? so that inp = [10,'trees',40,'desks']